# Swift - slowing down "too fast" animation (UIImage updates) -- aka is NSTimer the only option here?

Tags: ios, swift, delay, nstimer, ios8

Newbie to IOS programming - learning through Swift.  I'm writing a simple "slot machine / dice game".

I'm trying to show the user a flashing sequence of rolls before the "actual" roll appears.

```
func doFancyDiceRoll() {      
    for x in 1...100 {
        Die1.image = PipsImg[RollOne()]
        Die2.image = PipsImg[RollOne()]
        Die3.image = PipsImg[RollOne()]
    }          
}
```

Die1, etc., are defined as generic UIImage views.

In any case, I'm not seeing the 100x iterations, just the images at the end of the loop.  I'm assuming that either it redraws "too fast" or that IOS is trying to be smart, and only draws the last images so as to conserve resources.

I'll wildly guess that I need to either implement some kind of delay here, or, IOS needs to be told to explicitly draw out my images, and not try to outthink my intent.

For the delay, I've seen something about NSTimer, but nothing I saw seems to simply say something like "pause for .05" second, and the whole construct was unclear  as they were ObjC examples/conversions.

(Note: I've simplified things here --- normally, I would  store the value of RollOne() so I can use it later.  I also would like to make an array (or collection?) like Die[1].image, but that is another question.)

*========== Edit =======*

*OK, so I'm following up with more of my original code, merged in with that of @doctordoder so we can discuss a bit better.  Hopefully that is kosher. (If this appended question is too long, please advise me on the best way to post a lengthy follow-up directly.)*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


//( stripping out stuff unneeded for discussion )

// refers to same label below - works but kosher??    
@IBOutlet var btnRoll_x: UIView  

@IBAction func btnRoll(sender: AnyObject) {
    triggerRoll()
}

var timer : NSTimer? = nil
var rolls : Int = 0

func triggerRoll() {

    //hiding is bad UI, but until i know how to "disable & dim"
    btnRoll_x.hidden = true

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.10, target: self, selector: "doFancyDiceRoll", userInfo: nil, repeats: true);

}

func doFancyDiceRoll() {

    Die1.image = PipsImg[randomInt(6)]
    Die2.image = PipsImg[randomInt(6)]
    Die3.image = PipsImg[randomInt(6)]

    if (++rolls > 10)
    {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        rolls = 0   // DCB added this presumed missing line
        btnRoll_x.hidden = false //again, need to do this better
    }
}

}
```

Hopefully, my implementation of the code is what would have been intended.  I made some minor adjustments for (hopeful) clarity.

Good news is I have working code.  I have just enough understanding to get in place, but I'm fuzzy on some details.

Here is what I (think I) know...

We declare an NSTImer object, and a roll counter at the main level of the class. I note that in my original version, I had the roll counter scoped within the rolling function itself.    Took me a while to understand why it could not live in the DiceRoll loop itself, but now I do.  I'm going to express it poorly, but since the timer is going to call DiceRoll multiple instances, it needs to live outside the function.

The button btnRoll gets touched, and invokes triggerRoll().

To prevent the user from touching the button while we are in progress, which put us into a state where the roll counter never got to zero, I hide the button.  (I'll figure how to properly put in in disabled state later.)

The timer is set. It fires every .1 second (within limits), and is set to repeat.  (until .invalidate ).  And it "calls" the function doFancyDiceRoll via the selector: attribute.

So, the big change as previously noted is that doFancy..Roll() no longer loops.  It excites a single instance up updating the images.   It checks the counter, and if we reach the limit, we kill the timer, which stops the timer (invalidate).  (And I unhide the button, making it available again.)

So, a few things I am concerned/wondering about: I get the value of timers for other things that need to happen periodically (take health away every second, check a GPS position every 10 seconds, etc.).   It's seems a odd construct to force a screen refresh.

Frankly, I would have expected to see see something like this:

```
func doFancyDiceRoll() {      
    for x in 1...100 {
        Die1.image = PipsImg[RollOne()] // and 2 and 3 of course.....
        VIewController.forceRedraw <<=== something like this, or maybe
        ViewController.wait(.05)   <<==  this??  I dunno ;-)
    }          
}
```

instead we end up with about 20 extra lines or so.  I'd be interested in knowing if there other approaches that could work keeping the loop intact.

Anyway, assuming this is the one true way to go,  I guess my followup to this is how do I pass parameters, since this is not a "real" function call.  Trying 
    selector: "doFancyDiceRoll(40)"
was not objected to by the IDE, but failed in execution.

Comment: I did experiment some more, and changing my outer loop to 1000 or 10,000 server only to delay the time in which the final (and only) image was displayed).

Comment: Your code operates on the main thread. The entire loop is finished before the view is refreshed. I will try to elaborate in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same problem back in days, entire loop is finished before the view is refreshed as @doctordoder mentioned. Solved with using NSTimer

```
var rollCount = 0
let arrayOfImages = ["image01", "image02", "image03"]

var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("doFancyDiceRoll"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


func doFancyDiceRoll() {      
     if rollCount == 100 {
         timer.invalidate
         rollCount = 0
     { 
     else {
         //get images from array arrayOfImages[rollCount]
         rollCount++
     }
}
```

there could be typos, since I have no Xcode right now.

Comment: As noted to doc above, looks like I'm going to be jumping into the deep end pretty fast with NSTimer. ... I'm going to have followup questions later today. thx. d

Answer (score 2):

I have basically the same answer as above :(, but I thought I'd post it anyway.

```
var timer : NSTimer? = nil
var rolls : Int = 0

func doFancyDiceRoll() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.10, target: self, selector: "roll", userInfo: nil, repeats: true);

}

func roll() {
    println("rolling")
    Die1.image = PipsImg[RollOne()]
    Die2.image = PipsImg[RollOne()]
    Die3.image = PipsImg[RollOne()]
    if (++rolls > 100)
    {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, looks like I'm going to be jumping into the deep end pretty fast with NSTimer.  Stuck in your code, it works, played with it ...  I'm going to have followup questions later today. thx. d.

Comment: @user1639473 Yeah, let us know if you have any questions you can't figure out man. You shouldn't be intimidated by `NSTimer`, it basically has two functions, start doing something in the background `(scheduleTimerWithInterval`), and stop doing something in the background (`timer?.invalidate() timer = nil`).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than NSTimer and invalidating, you can use `dispatch_after` to do the work for you.

```
func rollDice(howManyTimes: Int) {
    die1.image = PipsImg[RollOne()]
    die2.image = PipsImg[RollOne()]
    die3.image = PipsImg[RollOne()]

    if howManyTimes > 0 {
        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) / 10.0))
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.rollDice(howManyTimes - 1)
        }
    }
}
```

This will run the code for the number of times specified, delaying each time by 0.1 seconds. It works like this: First it sets the images on each die, then, if there are more iterations, it does a `dispatch_after` to call itself with `rollDice(howManyTimes - 1)` 
With this, you don't need to maintain a NSTimer and it is pretty self contained.